# How to hide selected option from list

Tags: jquery

I have following HTMLselect fields:

```
<select name="title_42434" class="anyform-control form_select_tag"> 
  <option value="h1">h1</option> 
  <option value="h2">h2</option> 
  <option value="h3">h3</option> 
  <option value="h4">h4</option> 
  <option value="h5">h5</option> 
  <option value="h6">h6</option> 
</select>
```

Now, Using jQuery I am adding **selected** `attribute` when I choose any one of them.

**for e.g;**

I choose h2. jQuery will add **selected attribute.**
again, I choose h3. jQuery will add **selected attribute.**

But

I want it should be selected **only one option**. Means the last selected option will be removed.

**jQuery selected code:**

```
$(document).on('change', '.form_select_tag', function () {
  var op_val = $(this).val();    
  var field = $(this).closest('.row').attr('data-field');    
  $(this).find('option[value=' + op_val + ']').attr("selected", "selected");    

  //any other code to remove last selected option ?? 

  getPreview();
});
```

Comment: Why do you want to add the selected attribute? You should use `selectedIndex` instead.

Comment: `$(this).closest('.row').attr('data-field')` << what's this?

Comment: I will get a number from data-field attribute.

Comment: @creativeartbd you, OK, how do *we* get it? Is `$('select[name=title_' + field + ']')` some mystical Select buried in the vastness of your DOM?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan  sorry, don't understand? I have used that code to add selected attribute. Is there any way to remove the last selected attribute?

Comment: `$(this)` is already the current select. Why would you want to go for `$('select[name=title_' + field + ']')` it confuses me...

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan  I am new in jQuery. Do you have better solution?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Yes, $(this) can be used. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## CSS - Hide selected option

In pure CSS you could use the `option:checked` pseudo

```css
option:checked {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<select name="title_42434" class="anyform-control form_select_tag">
  <option selected disabled>Select Heading</option>
  <option value="h1">h1</option>
  <option value="h2">h2</option>
  <option value="h3">h3</option>
  <option value="h4">h4</option>
  <option value="h5">h5</option>
  <option value="h6">h6</option>
</select>
```

### jQuery - Hide selected option

To make `hidden` the currently selected `<option>`

```js
$(document).on('change', '.form_select_tag', function() {
  $(this).find('option').prop('hidden', i => this.selectedIndex == i);
});
```

```html
<select name="title_42434" class="anyform-control form_select_tag">
  <option selected disabled>Select Heading</option>
  <option value="h1">h1</option>
  <option value="h2">h2</option>
  <option value="h3">h3</option>
  <option value="h4">h4</option>
  <option value="h5">h5</option>
  <option value="h6">h6</option>
</select>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```